# Boost serial port 100% cpu usage

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

My problem seems to be related to https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/10496.

Simply opening a boost serial port and waiting for data cause one of the cpu
core of the embedded cpu to have 100% usage.

My hardware is the redpitaya STEMLAB 125-14 running Ubuntu 16.04. Some relevant
code snippets below:

```
// In the header

namespace ba = boost::asio;
typedef std::shared_ptr < boost::asio::serial_port serial_port_ptr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work_ptr;

class SerialPort {
    boost::asio::io_service m_io_service;
    serial_port_ptr m_port;
    work_ptr m_work;
    bool open(const std::string &portname);
};
```

```
// in the source file,

bool SerialPort::open(const std::string &portname) {

    m_port = serial_port_ptr(new ba::serial_port(m_io_service));
    m_work = work_ptr(new ba::io_service::work(m_io_service));

    m_port->open(portname, ec);
    if (ec) {
        std::cout << "open failed" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    m_io_service.reset();
    std::thread t(boost::bind(&ba::io_service::run, &m_io_service));
    t.detach();
}
```

If I comment out the last two lines, I get 0% cpu utilization. The code works
fine, I can read and send from the serial port. The serial port is a usb to
serial device (can this have any effect?).

Has anyone else experience this before and is there a workaround before it is
‘fixed’ by the boost developers or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I initially thought maybe the hardware is not ‘powerful enough’, so I installed Ubuntu on VMWare on my i7 laptop. And run only the serial code on it with the USB serial device and I obtained the same result - 100% CPU usage on one core.

I understand it is difficult to help without seeing the full code, so I created a simple code that demonstrate the problem: this can be downloaded from goo.gl/FD5RNE . For simplicity, the code is only looking for USB serial device and will try to open the first device it found.

If you remove the comment from sp.open(), you will see the cpu usage go close to full utilisation. Thanks.

Edit: Still no solution to this but since I am not expecting the serial device to send unsolicited messages to the client, I have changed the program to always close the port i.e. the write/read are executed together with port opened before write and closed after read.

This has worked well so far and I am getting an average CPU of around 0-0.8%. Maybe a future updates to boost will solve the issue.

Comment: This might indeed bve a (paltform specific?) bug. Here's something selfcontained: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dWxMKfHVRB/ It doesn't have a problem on my ubuntu box. 16.04 with boost 1.66

Comment: @sehe, thanks for your comment and for putting the code on watsebin. What hardware did you run it on?

Comment: Did you use a profiler to find out what function is taking all the CPU?

Comment: @BenVoigt, I just did now. Sorry I am not too familiar with Linux. I used gprof, several calls to boost::bi::bind_t and boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one are the functions taking most of the cpus (about 4% each) but there are several others too using 1-2% of the cpu. NB: Typing from my phone because can’t use stackoverflow desktop in the country I am (geo-restriction).